# How to join four tables in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have these four tables:

```
Items_a (item_id, name, cat_id, sub_cat_id)
Items_b (id, name2, cat_id, sub_cat_id)
Category (cat_id, cat_name)
Sub_category (sub_cat_id, sub_name, cat_id)
```

I want to join these table and trying following query but its not working:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT * FROM items_c AS c 
        JOIN category as t ON c.cat_id=t.cat_id
    ) as ct 
    JOIN sub_category as s ON ct.sub_cat_id=s.sub_cat_id
) as cts 
JOIN items_nc AS n ON cts.sub_cat_id=s.sub_cat_id
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: No need for 3 selects, only one -> `SELECT * FROM <A> JOIN <B> ON() JOIN <C> ON() JOIN <D> ON()` . All this sub select causing the error, I assume you're getting 'Ambigiously column..' error ?.

Comment: @Chris LOL in this case I dont think there is any confusion what ___not working___ means

Comment: What is your expected output? Also in your query where does items_c come from?

Comment: Grab a book or basic tutorial. Then get back to us.

Comment: Have a quick gander at [The Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) _I know its a radicle idea, but give it a go_

Comment: Please mention relationship between Items_a and Items_b and what does will be the output of this query?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, maybe we know what "not working" means here and maybe we don't. Either way I think encouraging a user to look at error messages and recognize that they are important enough to include is worthwhile.

Comment: @Chris Oh totally agree, I just saw the funny side of your comment. Sorry, keep smiling

Comment: @RiggsFolly, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM category c
INNER JOIN sub_category sc on c.cat_id = sc.cat_id
INNER JOIN items_a a on a.cat_id = c.cat_id AND a.sub_cat_id = sc.sub_cat_id
INNER JOIN items_b b on b.cat_id = c.cat_id AND b.sub_cat_id = sc.sub_cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is what you need, you can specify the list of column names instead of *

```
 SELECT * FROM items_c c JOIN category t ON c.cat_id=t.cat_id 
                         JOIN sub_category s ON ct.sub_cat_id=s.sub_cat_id 
                         JOIN items_nc n ON cts.sub_cat_id=s.sub_cat_id
```

You can refer [THIS](http://www.yourwebskills.com/mysqljoin2.php) further.

Answer (score 0):

Refer This

```
SELECT * 
FROM category c
INNER JOIN sub_category sc on c.cat_id = sc.cat_id
INNER JOIN item_a a on sc.sub_cat_id = a.sub_cat_id
INNER JOIN item_b b on sc.sub_cat_id = b.sub_cat_id
```